# Dynamically load CSS in Actionscript/Flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, mxml

**Problem Definition:** To be able to dynamically load a CSS at runtime to skin a Flex Application.

**More Information:** I've found that loading and applying a CSS is as simple as using "mx:style source="../assets/default.css"". But what I would like to do is something more like (pseudocode):

```
If (condition == 1)<br />
  mx:style source="../assets/style1.css"<br />
ElseIf (condition == 2)<br />
  mx:style source="../assets/style2.css"<br />
Else<br />
  mx:style source="../assets/default.css"<br />
```

I've started to look into the StyleManager class but want to know if there's a simpler implementation.

**Requirements:** I'd like to have something as simple as dropping a .css file into the /assets folder without requiring CSS->SWF compilation or anything complex like that.

Comment: It's not recommended, but look at the hack in : http://www.rubenswieringa.com/blog/cssloader

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the style tag, you're basically just inlining the style sheet. To my knowledge, there's no way to accomplish exactly what you're hoping to do. At the same time, you're probably best off doing this the way it's intended, using CSS to SWF compilation. That really isn't adding much complexity at all; you're just adding a single step in-between dropping your .css into /assets and adding it into your conditional.

See this article for more info:
http://onflash.org/ted/2007/01/flex-201-understand-runtime-css.php

Comment: I believe you are correct re: CSS -> SWF, I still do wish I could just substitute the CSS files. None the less, thanks for the link as it's a great resource.

I also found more here http://tinyurl.com/3asj9p

Comment: What's important to understand here is that Flash Player doesn't intercept CSS (or even MXML, for that matter) at runtime: it only understands the bytecode that executes inside the AVM. MXML compiles to ActionScript which is compiled to bytecode and CSS needs to take a similar path as well.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a link showing how to load css into actionscript at run-time.  I used it for a Flex project:
http://www.developphp.com/view.php?tid=129